# Cool fan 2007 jetta wolfsburg

Tags: vw

Does anyone know how much watts the 2007 jetta wolfsburg cooling fan is? Will a 150 watts fan work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you measure the current flow when it is working then you will know , assume 10A then times 12 = 120W...

But that is not what you really need - it is the airflow in litres / minute or cubic feet / minute that you must match.